# I want to change the style in a item with a button click in the item, but when i click the button only the first item in the forech changes

Tags: javascript, php

I called an api from a website to make a list of items in my own website.

I do that with `foreach`. The list gets imported correctly, but I have a little problem.

Each item in the list has an description with `display: none;` and each item also has a button. If I click that button I want to make the `display: inline;`

I tried a lot of things, but every time I click a button only the first item in the foreach list changes.

I am not really good at explaining, but hopefully someone can help me.

```cs
        <?php
        foreach ($items as $item):
            echo "<script> 
            
            function hide_post(){
                hideshow = document.querySelector('#showMoreLessId');
                hideshowtext = document.querySelector('#showMoreLess');
                if (hideshow.style.display == 'inline'){
                    hideshow.style.display = 'none';
                    hideshowtext.innerHTML = 'Toon meer';
                }else{
                    hideshow.style.display = 'inline';
                    hideshowtext.innerHTML = 'Toon minder';
                }
            }
            </script>";
        ?>
            <div class="item" id="item">
                <h4>Versie: <?= $item->name;  ?></h4>
                <div id="showMoreLessId">
                    <p>Issues in versie: <?= $res->issuesFixedCount; ?> </p>
                    <p>Afgeronde issues: <?= $roundedIssue;?> </p>
                    <p>Nog te verwerken issues: <?= $uns->issuesUnresolvedCount;?> </p>
                </div>
                <small><?= $item->releaseDate; ?></small>
                <a onclick="hide_post()" id="showMoreLess">Toon meer</a>
                <a>|</a>
                <a href="<?='version/?version=' . $item->name; ?>">Meer info</a>
            </div>
            <?php
        endforeach;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('#showMoreLessId');` will only get the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because you're repeating the same `id` on multiple elements in the DOM as you loop to create the HTML.

To fix this issue apply `class` attributes to the repeated content instead, and then use `document.querySelectorAll()` to retrieve them. Note that you will need to loop through the returned collection as well.

In addition you will need to use DOM traversal to find the elements related to the clicked `a` element.

In addition, your JS function should only be declared *once*, outside of your PHP loop.

Here's a working example with the above changes applied. Note that I also changed the class names to better describe the purpose of the elements.

```js
// JS logic only defined once, separate from your PHP code...  

document.querySelectorAll('.toggle').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', hide_post);
});

function hide_post(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const toggle = e.target;
  const item = e.target.closest('.item');
  const details = item.querySelector('.details');
  
  if (details.style.display == 'inline') {
    details.style.display = 'none';
    toggle.innerHTML = 'Toon meer';
  } else {
    details.style.display = 'inline';
    toggle.innerHTML = 'Toon minder';
  }
}
```

```css
.details { display: none; }
```

```html
<!-- HTML content generated by your PHP loop... -->

<div class="item">
  <h4>Versie: $item->name1</h4>
  <div class="details">
    <p>Issues in versie: $res->issuesFixedCount1</p>
    <p>Afgeronde issues: $roundedIssue1</p>
    <p>Nog te verwerken issues: $uns->issuesUnresolvedCount1</p>
  </div>
  <small>$item->releaseDate1</small>
  <a href="#" class="toggle">Toon meer</a>
  <a>|</a>
  <a href="<?='version/?version=' . $item->name; ?>">Meer info</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <h4>Versie: $item->name2</h4>
  <div class="details">
    <p>Issues in versie: $res->issuesFixedCount2</p>
    <p>Afgeronde issues: $roundedIssue2</p>
    <p>Nog te verwerken issues: $uns->issuesUnresolvedCount2</p>
  </div>
  <small>$item->releaseDate2</small>
  <a href="#" class="toggle">Toon meer</a>
  <a>|</a>
  <a href="<?='version/?version=' . $item->name; ?>">Meer info</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <h4>Versie: $item->name2</h4>
  <div class="details">
    <p>Issues in versie: $res->issuesFixedCount2</p>
    <p>Afgeronde issues: $roundedIssue2</p>
    <p>Nog te verwerken issues: $uns->issuesUnresolvedCount2</p>
  </div>
  <small>$item->releaseDate2</small>
  <a href="#" class="toggle">Toon meer</a>
  <a>|</a>
  <a href="<?='version/?version=' . $item->name; ?>">Meer info</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <h4>Versie: $item->name2</h4>
  <div class="details">
    <p>Issues in versie: $res->issuesFixedCount2</p>
    <p>Afgeronde issues: $roundedIssue2</p>
    <p>Nog te verwerken issues: $uns->issuesUnresolvedCount2</p>
  </div>
  <small>$item->releaseDate2</small>
  <a href="#" class="toggle">Toon meer</a>
  <a>|</a>
  <a href="<?='version/?version=' . $item->name; ?>">Meer info</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I used your code, but for some reason only the second and fourth item works

Comment: In that case I'd guess that maybe there's an issue with how you copied the code, as all instances work fine in the example above.

Comment: found the solution. i forgot to put the javascript outside the foreach... But really thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `hide_post` function in a loop, overriding the previous `hide_post` function. In your case, it's better to define the function outside the loop and pass a unique parameter to the function. Assuming the item name is unique and does not contain spaces, you can use the following.

```
function hide_post(postId){
     hideshow = document.querySelector('#showMoreLessId_'+postId);
     hideshowtext = document.querySelector('#showMoreLess_'+postId);
     if (hideshow.style.display == 'inline'){
        hideshow.style.display = 'none';
        hideshowtext.innerHTML = 'Toon meer';
     } else {
        hideshow.style.display = 'inline';
        hideshowtext.innerHTML = 'Toon minder';
     }
}
```

From your loop in PHP define the like as following,

```php
<a onclick="hide_post('<?= $item->name;  ?>')" id="showMoreLess_"<?= $item->name; ?>>Toon meer</a>
```